# Get related field in django template

Tags: django

I have two models:

```
class Button(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
    anchor = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                   related_name='anchor', blank=True, null=True,)

class Section(models.Model):
    ...
    transliterate_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, 
                                                           null=True)
```

Now I wanna to get transliterate_name in my template. I use this field as id to article. And i want to assign it to the button id in navigation menu.
There is my template:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
        {% for menu_btn in menu_buttons %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#{{ ??? }}" class="nav-link">
                     {{ menu_btn.title }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

in my views:

```
class SectionView(ListView):
    queryset = Section.objects.filter(name_visible=True)
    context_object_name = 'sections'
    extra_context = {
        'articles': Article.objects.all(),
        'menu_buttons': Buttons.objects.all(),
    }

    template_name = 'sections/sections.html'
```

Any advise please.

Comment: What is in your urls.py?

Comment: @rarblack: the URLs are irrelevant: this is an *anchor*, the URL starts with a "hash", like `#foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the related `Section` object, by fetching the `anchor` attribute:

```
<a href="#{{ menu_btn.anchor.transliterate_name }}" class="nav-link">
```

Since you will fetch the related attribute of *every* `Button` object, it it better to fetch all these `Section`s in *one* fetch with `.select_related(..)`:

```
class SectionView(ListView):
    queryset = Section.objects.filter(name_visible=True)
    context_object_name = 'sections'
    extra_context = {
        'articles': Article.objects.all(),
        'menu_buttons': Buttons.objects.select_related('anchor').all(),
    }

    template_name = 'sections/sections.html'
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately its not working: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'section'. Choices are: anchor.

Comment: @Coveraver: yes, it should be `anchor`. Is there a particular reason why you named it `anchor`, and not `section`?

Comment: no. But if I change to anchor in 'menu buttons': Buttons.objects.select_related('anchor').all(), there is no link - href="#"

Comment: @Coveraver: then either the names of the model you share do not fully match your model, or the `anchor`, and/or `transliterate_name` is `None` or the empty string. What happens if you inspect the database?

Comment: in table sections_section i have a transliterate_name

Comment: @Coveraver: yes but does `anchor_id` in `section_button` contains non-NULL values, does the `transliterate_name` contains non-NULL and non-emptystring values?

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT section_button.* section_section.* FROM section_button LEFT OUTER JOIN section_section ON section_button.section_id = section_section.id`? This is after all the "list" of buttons together with the related `Section`s. It is thus the "content" you want to render so to speak.

Comment: I have not section_button . https://photos.app.goo.gl/rKJEi7v7gnzWUc449

Comment: @Coveraver: well the `appname_button`, with `appname` the name of the app where you constructed the `Button` class.

Comment: I have this structure photos.app.goo.gl/rKJEi7v7gnzWUc449

Comment: Then what is the outcome of `SELECT menu_button.* section_section.* FROM menu_button LEFT OUTER JOIN section_section ON menu_button.section_id = section_section.id`?

Comment: When I try this in python console                                                                              
 b = Button.objects.select_related('section').all()
b
<QuerySet [<Button: to about section>]>                                                                        to about section - the name of a button

Comment: @Coveraver: yes, the problem is **not** the query, it is very likely simply the database that contains no data...

Comment: I am sorry, but can't execute SELECT menu_button.* section_section.* FROM menu_button LEFT OUTER JOIN section_section ON menu_button.section_id = section_section.id into sqlite - invalid syntax

Comment: And why there is no data? After all, there is a FK

Comment: I forgot a comma, `SELECT menu_button.*, section_section.* FROM menu_button LEFT OUTER JOIN section_section ON menu_button.section_id = section_section.id`.

Comment: @Coveraver: because: (a) the FK refers to a non-existing object, (b) the `transliterate_name` of that object is NULL, (c) the `transliterate_name` of that object is the empty string.

Comment: I updated link to google photos. There is data in the database

Comment: sorry! I was inattentive. menu_buttons.anchor.transliterate_name instead menu_btn.anchor.transliterate_name